# Delete common elements in two lists

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, programming-languages

I was trying to implement a function that deletes all common elements in two lists using Scheme.

Here is the function I wrote.

```
#| delete elem from lis|#
(define (delete ele lis)
  (cond
    ((null? ele) lis)
    ((null? lis) '())
    ((equal? ele (car lis)) (cdr lis))
    (else (cons (car lis) (delete ele (cdr lis))))
    )
  )
#|delete element from l1 which is in l2 |#
(define (remove l1 l2)
  (if(null? l2) l1
     (if(null? l1) '()
        (remove (delete (car l2) l1) (cdr l2)) )))

(define (remove-common l1 l2)
  (list (remove l1 l2) (remove l2 l1)))
```

The function works well for some inputs, but some didn't work well. How can I fix my code to remove all the common elements in two lists?

```
(remove-common '(1 2) '(2 4)) #| output : ((1) (4))|#
(remove-common '(1 3) '(2 4)) #| output :((1 3) (2 4)) |#
```

I expected

```
(remove-common '(1 2 3) '(1 2 2 3 4))
```

to yield `(() 4)`, removing the 1s, 2s, and 3s from each list because those are common to both. But the actual result is `(() (2 4))`.

I'm using R5RS for Scheme.

Comment: That result looks right to me. What were you hoping the answer would be, and why?

Comment: @amalloy For the last example, the correct output should be (()(4) instead of (()(2 4)), because 1, 2 and 3 are the common elements in two lists.

Comment: Looks like your `delete` only removes the first matching element, not all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. As @Shawn says, the problem is with the function `delete`. What you're trying to write here is a `filter` function.

For this there are two cases:

1. Keep value. For `(filter x xs)`, `cons` x onto the front of `(filter xs)`
2. Lose value. Just move to `(filter xs)`

Your delete function correctly handles case 1, but not case 2.

The delete function should be:

```
#| delete elem from lis|#    
(define (delete ele lis)
  (cond
     ((null? ele) lis)
     ((null? lis) '())
     ((equal? ele (car lis)) (delete ele (cdr lis))) ; amendment
     (else (cons (car lis) (delete ele (cdr lis))))
    )
  )

> (remove-common '(1 2 3) '(1 2 2 3 4))
(() (4))
```